# Deleting decimals in big datatables

Tags: r

I have a datatable with approximately 1 million rows and several columns. A certain column has 7 digits number in every row. I need to create a new column with the 5 first digits of the numbers of the previous row.

Example:

Column 1 =  8312990

Column 2 =  83129

To do that, I divided Column 1 by 100, and now I need to delete the decimal values. I have tried to use "round" and "format" but it seems they only work with a maximum of 10k rows.

I also used “options (digits=0)” which at first worked. However, I could not subset the rows with the numbers I wanted (5 digits), so I suspect this is just a display setting and the decimals are still there.

Any ideas on how to delete decimal values from 1 million rows in a datatable? Many thanks.

Comment: From your example it looks like you want `floor(8312990/100)`.  Are you sure the 10k rows is not just the maximum printing to the console?

Comment: @Richard Scriven: floor solved my problem, thank you. I'm not sure why round did not do it.

Comment: Round will not remove digits left of the decimal, that's why.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Thanks for the help and sorry for the misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function floor

```
> so=read.csv("so3.csv",header=F)
> so
        V1
1  6075210
2  8263901
3  1251997
4  1800517
5  7481683
6  3706369
7  3235733
8  9541251
9  6389095
10 9672051
11 1624036
12 3575045
13 7592376
14 8395012
15 5933096
16 2358357
17 3440983
18 5948804
19 7215281
20 1698528
21 5133276
22 5436095
23 5698401
24 6927701
> so$V2=floor(so$V1/100)
> so
        V1    V2
1  6075210 60752
2  8263901 82639
3  1251997 12519
4  1800517 18005
5  7481683 74816
6  3706369 37063
7  3235733 32357
8  9541251 95412
9  6389095 63890
10 9672051 96720
11 1624036 16240
12 3575045 35750
13 7592376 75923
14 8395012 83950
15 5933096 59330
16 2358357 23583
17 3440983 34409
18 5948804 59488
19 7215281 72152
20 1698528 16985
21 5133276 51332
22 5436095 54360
23 5698401 56984
24 6927701 69277
>
```